# Skipping inner joins in multiple tables mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I built a large script with several inner joins working as "conditions" (instead of using WHERE clauses). As a sample:

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM Table1 T1
    INNER JOIN Table2 T2
        ON T1.id = T2.id
    INNER JOIN Table3 T3
        ON T2.id = T3.id
    INNER JOIN Table4 T4
        ON T1.id = T4.id
```

etc...

Under certain conditions I need to skip one or several inner joins.
Till now, I had to duplicate the script commenting out the lines with the joins I don't need.
Would it be any way to work with variables or IF clauses to skip a join, or at least a "select all" way?

Comment: under what conditions you need to skip some joins, for example?

Comment: Use left outer joins, and then control the conditions in the where clause. Less performant, but gives you more control.

Comment: @Axarydax Whatever conditions according to script variables. Something like (in bash) "if $VAR="YES" then..."

Comment: can you give sample records with desired result?

Comment: @muhmud Yes, I am struggling with inner joins because I was convinced the performance was much better than left joins + where clauses that in fact was the structure I was using till now. I am afraid I will return to the classics...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming php:

```
$SQL = "
SELECT T1.*
FROM Table1 T1
    INNER JOIN Table2 T2
        ON T1.id = T2.id" . ($variable1 == x ? " OR TRUE=TRUE" : "") . "
    INNER JOIN Table3 T3
        ON T2.id = T3.id" . ($variable2 == y ? " OR TRUE=TRUE" : "") . "
    INNER JOIN Table4 T4
        ON T1.id = T4.id" . ($variable3 == z ? " OR TRUE=TRUE" : "")
```

But I'm sure you should rather build the query dynamically:

```
$SQL = "
SELECT T1.*
FROM Table1 T1";

if ($variable1 == x) {
    $SQL .= " INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.id = T2.id";
}

if ($variable2 == y) {
    $SQL .= " INNER JOIN Table3 T3 ON T2.id = T3.id";
}

if ($variable3 == z) {
    $SQL .= " INNER JOIN Table4 T4 ON T3.id = T4.id";
}
```

etc. with all your joins.

Comment: This is the kind of idea I was searching for, although as unfortunately I am using bash can not apply as it is. I was expecting a way of coding the query itself, instead of the lenguage used to run it. Thanks!

Comment: i think you can wish bash, even with user inputs, but I'm not good enough to help you on this one!